# Marklogic - Handling documents while removing a node from cluster

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I have a MarkLogic cluster with 10 nodes. Each has a forest associated with it. If I am planning to retire a node from the cluster, how do I handle the documents in that node? Does MarkLogic automatically move the documents to the other nodes when it "leaves" the cluster or should I be doing a re-balancing before retiring the node?

Comment: You should really have more than one forest on each of your nodes too. Forests are a key means for MarkLogic to parallelize ingestion and queries. Replicating forests across nodes is also a way to provide high availability for the database. The exact number of forests per node will be depend on many factors, but is almost always `> 1`.

Comment: For more detail on forest recommendations, please see [Forest Sizes Per Data Node Host](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/cluster/scalability#id_96443). I've also seen a presentation suggesting six as the starting number of forests per host, to be adjusted based on the reading that I linked to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you try to leave the cluster without moving any data, you will notice it won't let you. See also the [Admin guide](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/hosts#id_97383) and the [Scalability, Availability, and Failover Guide](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/cluster/config_cluster#id_85628). Basically, you need to:

- retire all forests assigned to the host you want to remove from the cluster
- make sure rebalance moves all files to the other nodes (this normally starts automatically after you retire a forest)
- once all files have been moved off the host (may take a while), detach all relevant forests from their databases
- delete all forests on that host
- and only then the host can leave the cluster

Additional steps might be required if replication and/or failover is involved. You will probably need to redistribute replica forests and failover hosts.

HTH!

Comment: If this answers your question, please mark it as accepted -- that rewards grtjn and helps us keep track of which questions still need work.